# authorization type bearer token on postman and request data from the API which requires a token bearer with flutter

Tags: api, flutter, dart, postman, bearer-token

im trying to request data from my API and to get the data, it requires a bearer token which can be obtain by log-in. and as a frontend I created a function to save and request from the UI to the API. I'm using flutter framework for the UI.

I've managed to create a function to store the bearer token generated at login, which keeps the user logged in. and it works by saving the bearer token in sharedpref.

```
login() async {
final response = await http.post(
  "https://api.batulimee.com//v1_ship/login_app",
  body: {"email": email, "password": password},
);  
final data = jsonDecode(response.body);
String status = data['status'];
String pesan = data['message'];
String apikey = data['data']['apikey'];
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
prefs.setString('apikey', apikey);

if (status == "success") {
  Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(PageRouteBuilder(
      pageBuilder: (_, __, ___) => new bottomNavBar(),
      transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 600),
      transitionsBuilder:
          (_, Animation<double> animation, __, Widget child) {
        return Opacity(
          opacity: animation.value,
          child: child,
        );
      }));
  print(pesan);
  print(apikey);
} else {
  print(pesan);
}
}
```

heres the response.

```
{
"status": "success",
"data": {
    "apikey": "UUFmb0w3WlI4Q01qOWRTamgxOFVZRjhIeWhFMkN3T205R20xZXNpYw==",
    "id_user": 50,
    "id_role": "8",
    "name_role": "Ship Owner",
    "email": "me@gmail.com",
    "phone": "0210201",
    "saldo": "0",
    "photo": "https://cdn.batulimee.com/foto_user/avatar.png"
},
"message": "login successfully "
}
```

and now I want to create a function that can get user profile data, and where to get this data requires the bearer token which I got from login. I need this so that the user can edit their name, password, or other data in the user's profile and save it.

My backend has created the API get my_profile. which I explained earlier, to get this requires a token bearer that is the same as the token bearer we got earlier from login. And now it's my job to get the get my_profile data using a function in flutter.

heres the response from the API get my_profile.

```
{
"status": "success",
"data": {
"id_user": 49,
"id_role": "8",
"name_role": "Ship Owner",
"first_name": "a",
"last_name": "f",
"email": "afriansyahm86@gmail.com",
"phone": "082258785595",
"saldo": "0",
"company_name": "aa",
"company_address": "jl kav pgri",
"photo": "https://batulimee.com/foto_user/avatar.png"
},
"message": "get profile detail successfully "
}
```

[image]

How is the function to store the bearer token into Authorization so I can get my_profile data ? please help me.... :(

Answer (score 1):

make an api class :

```
import 'package:http/io_client.dart';
class Api {

  String _token;

 final Client http =IOClient(HttpClient()
    ..badCertificateCallback = _certificateCheck
    ..connectionTimeout = const Duration(seconds: kConnectionTimeoutSeconds));
static bool _certificateCheck(X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) =>
  host.endsWith('EXAMPLE.com'); // Enter your url for api here
  String GetToken() {
    return _token;
  }
Future<bool> setToken(String token) async {
    _token = token;
    return Future.value(true);
  }
Map<String, String> get headers => {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Authorization": "Bearer $_token",
      };
```

}

in your login use the setToken:

await _api.setToken(apikey);

next for your profile or any request in api class:

```
Future<ProfileResponse> getProfile() async {
    var url = "$urlPrefix/api/v1/profile";

    var response = await http.get(url, headers: headers);

    if (response.statusCode != 200) {
      print(
          "$response");
      var parsed = json.decode(response.body);
      var message = parsed["message"];
      if (message != null) {
        throw message;
      }

      throw Exception(
          "Request to $url failed with status ${response.statusCode}: ${response.body}");
    }
    // return the response you want 
    return json.decode(response.body);
  }
```

Comment: final Client http = StatsInterceptor(IOClient(HttpClient()
    ..badCertificateCallback = _certificateCheck
    ..connectionTimeout = const Duration(seconds: kConnectionTimeoutSeconds)));
  String GetToken() {
    return _token;
  }

Comment: and what is  StatsInterceptor?

Comment: you can remove the stateIntercepror, I have it in my code to retry if failed.
however you can simply use:
Client http = http.Client();

Comment: aahh i see, thank you. im sorry can you explain about setToken: await _api.setToken(apikey);?

Comment: add that line in the login class  below this:

`print(apikey);`
you have to import the api class here and add it as a final in your login class
and then you can use it